# Latency of accessing main memory is almost the same order of sending a packet

Tags: performance, networking, disk, low-latency

Looking at Jeff Dean's famous latency guides

```html
Latency Comparison Numbers (~2012)
----------------------------------
L1 cache reference                           0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                            5   ns
L2 cache reference                           7   ns                      14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                           25   ns
Main memory reference                      100   ns                      20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy             3,000   ns        3 us
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network       10,000   ns       10 us
Read 4K randomly from SSD*             150,000   ns      150 us          ~1GB/sec SSD
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory     250,000   ns      250 us
Round trip within same datacenter      500,000   ns      500 us
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*     1,000,000   ns    1,000 us    1 ms  ~1GB/sec SSD, 4X memory
Disk seek                           10,000,000   ns   10,000 us   10 ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    20,000,000   ns   20,000 us   20 ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA    150,000,000   ns  150,000 us  150 ms
```

One thing which looks somewhat uncanny to me is the time taken to read 1MB sequentially from disk is only 10 times faster than sending a round trip packet across the Atlantic. Can anyone give me more intuition why this feels right.

Comment: "Main memory" does not, generally, refer to a disk or other non-volatile storage: it refers to RAM.

Answer (score 3):

> **Q** : *1MB SEQ-HDD-READ ~ 10x faster than a CA/NL trans-atlantic RTT - **why** this feels right?*

---

Some "old" values ( with a few cross-QPI/NUMA updates [from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307727) ) to start from:

```
           0.5 ns - CPU L1 dCACHE reference
           1   ns - speed-of-light (a photon) travel a 1 ft (30.5cm) distance
           5   ns - CPU L1 iCACHE Branch mispredict
           7   ns - CPU L2  CACHE reference
          71   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA best  case on XEON E5-46*
         100   ns - MUTEX lock/unlock
         100   ns - CPU own DDR MEMORY reference
         135   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA best  case on XEON E7-*
         202   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA worst case on XEON E7-*
         325   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA worst case on XEON E5-46*
      10,000   ns - Compress 1 KB with Zippy PROCESS (+GHz,+SIMD,+multicore tricks)
      20,000   ns - Send 2 KB over 1 Gbps NETWORK
     250,000   ns - Read 1 MB sequentially from MEMORY
     500,000   ns - Round trip within a same DataCenter
  10,000,000   ns - DISK seek
  10,000,000   ns - Read 1 MB sequentially from NETWORK
  30,000,000   ns - Read 1 MB sequentially from DISK
 150,000,000   ns - Send a NETWORK packet CA -> Netherlands
|   |   |   |
|   |   | ns|
|   | us|
| ms|
```

## Trans-Atlantic Network RTT :

- Global optical networks work roughly at a speed of light ( `300.000.000 m/s` )
- LA(CA)-AMS(NL) packet has to travel not the geodetical *"distance"*, but over a set of continental and trans-atlantic *"submarine"* cables, the length of which is way longer ( see the [map](https://www.submarinecablemap.com/#/submarine-cable/tat-14) )

These factors do **not** *"improve"* - only the transport capacity is growing, with add-on latencies introduced in light-amplifiers, retiming units and other L1-PHY / L2-/L3-networking technologies are kept under control, as small as possible.

So the LA(CA)-AMS(NL) RTT will remain, using this technology, [the same ~ 150 ms](https://wondernetwork.com/pings/)

Using other technology, LEO-Sat Cubes - as an example - the "distance" will only grow from ~ 9000 km P2P, by a pair of additional GND/LEO segments, plus by a few addition LEO/LEO hops, which introduce "longer" distance, add-on hop/hop re-processing latencies and capacity will not get any close to the current optical transports available, so no magic jump "back to the future" is to be expected ( we still miss the DeLorean ).

---

### The HDD Disk :

- HDD-s can have very fast and very short transport-path for moving the data, but the **`READ`**-ops have to wait for the physical / mechanical operations of the media-reading heads ( that takes most of the time here, not the actual data-transfer to the host RAM )
- HDD-s are rotational devices, the disk has to "align" where to start the read, which costs the first about **`10 [ms]`**
- HDD-s devices store data into a static structure of **heads**( 2+, reading physical signals from the magnetic plates' surfaces ):**cylinders**( concentric circular zones on the plate, into which a cyl-aligned reading-head gets settled by disk-head micro-controller):**sector**( angular-sections of the cylinder, each carrying a block of the same sized data ~ 4KB, 8KB, ... )

These factors do **not** *"improve"* - all commodity produced drives remain at industry selected angular speeds of about { 5k4 | 7k2 | 10k | 15k | 18k }-spins/min (RPM). This means, that if a well-compacted data-layouts are maintained on such a disk, one continuous head:cylinder aligned reading round the whole cylinder will take:

```
>>> [ 1E3 / ( RPM / 60. ) for RPM in ( 5400, 7200, 10000, 15000, 18000 ) ]

11.1 ms per CYL @  5k4 RPM disk,
 8.3 ms per CYL @  7k2 RPM disk,
 6.0 ms per CYL @ 10k  RPM disk,
 4.0 ms per CYL @ 15k  RPM disk,
 3.3 ms per CYL @ 18k  RPM disk.
```

Data-density is also limited by the magnetic media properties. Spintronics R&D will bring some more densely stored data, yet the last 30 years have been well inside the limits of the reliable magnetic storage.

More is to be expected from a trick to co-parallel-read from several heads at-once, yet this goes against the design of the embedded microcontrollers, so most of the reading goes but sequentially, from one head after another, into the HDD-controller onboard buffers, best if no cyl-to-cyl heads mechanical re-alignment were to take place ( technically this depends on the prior data-to-disc layout, maintained by the O/S and possible care of disk-optimisers ( originally called disk disk-"compression", which just tried to re-align the known sequences of FAT-described data-blocks, so as to follow the most optimal trajectory of head:cyl:sector transitions, depending most on the actual device's head:head and cyl:cyl latencies ). So even the most optimistic data-layout takes `~ 13..21 [ms]` to seek-and-read but one head:cyl-path

> **Laws of Physics decide**

Answer (score 1):

Some numbers from 2020.

Load from L1 is 4 cycles on Intel Coffee Lake and Ryzen (0.8nsec on a 5GHz CPU).

Load from memory is ~215 cycles on Intel Coffee Lake (43nsec on a 5GHz CPU). ~280 cycles on Ryzen.